# Uninstalling KDE from Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, kde, plasma

Ok, as I could not find the solution of my problem here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/214208/kde-plasma-is-totally-crashed-ubuntu-12-10

I want to uninstall kde desktop environment. Now I am in Unity. How can I uninstall KDE?

Note: I will install it again after uninstalling process..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu

This website did it for me. It's the first one on the page just copy and paste it into your terminal.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Well, u can use synaptic, and remove all KDE packages, and add kubuntu-desktop to remove ;)